# Filter a big table in google sheets with unique

Tags: google-sheets, formula, unique

sorry for my (not perfectly) english...
I want to find the last occurrence in "C2:H17" of a number and then display column A and column B about it.
I've tried a lot and just can't get it right.

My last idea was this:
I created a helper column J to list all uniques once.
`=UNIQUE(FILTER(FLATTEN($C$2:$H);FLATTEN($C$2:$H)<>""))t`
In addition to the unique items, the references to columns A and column B should now be displayed. It is to be searched from bottom to top, so that the most recent date is always output.

[her is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLmrF.png)

Maybe it is also possible to use only one formula, which filters the unique items and displays the desired neighboring columns.

I hope you can help me.

Greeting at all

I tried this `=UNIQUE(FILTER(FLATTEN($C$2:$H);FLATTEN($C$2:$H)<>""))`

And also I tried a bit with this formula:
`=CHOOSECOLS(Filter(A2:H17;ZÄHLENWENN(J2:J;(C2:C17))+ZÄHLENWENN(J2:J;D2:D17)+ZÄHLENWENN(J2:J;E2:E17)+ZÄHLENWENN(J2:J;F2:F17)+ZÄHLENWENN(J2:J;G2:G17)+ZÄHLENWENN(J2:J;H2:H17));1;2)`

But it gives me not that output I want.

EDIT:
Here is an Link to my [demo-sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lPt2ufUrtaq1_p5Fw99alyOvshdb64h4_-PtlhM60Ec/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Hi. I edited my question and added a link to the demo-sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [may try](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lPt2ufUrtaq1_p5Fw99alyOvshdb64h4_-PtlhM60Ec/edit#gid=1429576336):

```
=map(unique(tocol(C3:H;1));lambda(Σ;iferror({
            Σ\
            choosecols(torow(index(if(C3:H=Σ;A3:A;));1);-1)\
            choosecols(torow(index(if(C3:H=Σ;B3:B;));1);-1)
     })))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thank you for that suggestion. It works perfectly. But it's also a bit slow. Is there perhaps a formula (maybe another way) that would make it run faster?